# Beautifusoupl Issue about extracting text with inside html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html code:

```
<div class="_czm8crp">Joined in 2010<div class="_36rlri"></div></div>
```

I want to get "Joined in 2010".

I write code:

```
url = "https://www.airbnb.com/users/show/28845283"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

info = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "_czm8crp"})
for item in info:
    print(item.text)
```

However, it didn't show the one I need, it only shows other without div class "__36rlri" text. Could somebody help me fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by using its parent's div info**. Here is the html code:

```
<div style="margin-top:8px"><div class="_czm8crp">Joined in 2010<div class="_36rlri"></div></div></div>
```

Solution:

```
info = soup.find("div", attrs={"style": "margin-top:8px"})
print(info.text)
```

Result:

```
Joined in 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Make sure that you have provided html code in the `html` variable.

This part could be added by JavaScript and you can see it in the browser, but not in the raw response.

EDIT: As expected, the url you provided doesn't send that part of the html without proper preparation. First of all, you should pass the header with User-Agent in your request. But even after that, the information that you need is not in the html, but in the script that's part of that html.
So, I suggest you use `re` library for that kind of extraction.

Example:

```py
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.airbnb.com/users/show/28845283"
r = requests.get(url, headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
})
html = r.text
result = re.search(r'<div class="\S+?">(Joined in \d+?)<div', html)
print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: I've edited my post. Could you please have a look at that html?